# Generate API Routes using FOSRestBundle containing the same common parameter

Tags: symfony, routes, fosrestbundle

I'm using FOSRestBundle to build my API, but I'm stuck in middle of something I need which is every API route should contain a default parameter, an API key to check for permissions, but I don't want to put it on every action on my API because I'm not going to use it on my controller, I'm just going to use to authenticate the user.

So I would like to know if I can generate automatically those routes creating some sort of generic route that all the routes inherit for that particular route.

To clarify things I'm going to put a few examples of I want to get:

I have this action on my controller:

```
public function getSomethingAction($apiKey)
{
  //My logic goes here
}
```

So the route generated by the bundle would be:

```
/api/somethings/{apiKey}
```

But at this point,the apikey parameter is being already used, so I don't want there, but if I don't put that parameter in the method, I would get:

```
/api/somethings
```

I hope these examples clarify the things I want to achieve.

Thank in advance for every answer I get.

Regards

Víctor

Answer (score 0):

I think you should reconsider supplying the API key in the resource URL. I would suggest suplying the API key through HTTP header "Authorization" and implementing custom Symfony authenticator as described in the document below:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html